# Arc error executing function Skyline with surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, error-999999

Trying to get a skyline for a set of 3D points based on a DEM (LiDAR based raster), but get the catch all error 999999.
The surface is optional and the function works when no surface is assigned. All other optional settings are set to default.
I've found the same problem posed elsewhere, but no solution yet ([GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/99462) and [Shadow Analysis Tool Comments](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/01/10/updated-shadow-analysis-template/)).
I've attempted in Arcmap 10.1 and 10.2.2. I've also tried copying the raster to into a .gbd, converting the raster to integer, and executing the function from python with no luck. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I am completely guessing, but based on other visibility analysis errors I've had: are the points and the raster in the same projection?

Comment: Both are in the same projection. I've been able to run Viewshed on the same DEM and set of points (only difference being it was before running feature to 3D by attribute on the points for skyline).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please remove it and use the `comment` button instead.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93396)

Answer (score 1):

I usually find this error when you have skipped a few attributes and entered something after a few skips. The functions gets confused as to whether you are entering an input/output layer or an aesthetic variable to modify the function or which aesthetic variable. Defaults also need to be specified in certain cases. It is usually resolved by assigning the variable to the existing attribute name field inside the function.

For example:

```
arcpy.Skyline_3d(in_observer_point_features = file, out_feature_class = output_layer,
                 virtual_surface_radius= surfRad, virtual_surface_elevation = surfElev, 
                 in_features = obstructionFCs,feature_lod =LOD,from_azimuth_value_or_field = fromAzim, 
                 to_azimuth_value_or_field=toAzim, azimuth_increment_value_or_field=incAzim, 
                 max_horizon_radius = maxHorizRad, segment_skyline = segSky, scale_to_percent = scale, 
                 scale_according_to = scaleAcc,scale_method = scaleMethod)
```